# Python Pandas: Comparing two columns and returning string value if first column include character in the string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I have 2 columns first with string including X or F and second is empty.
If there is any X in column 1 I want to assign 'YES' to second column if there is no X assign 'NO'
Every time I run my code it is assigning value 'YES' to all of them

[This example how it should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdsMC.png)

My code:

```
for row in df['Column2']:
    if df['Column1'].str.contains('X').any():
        df['Column2'] = 'YES'
    else:
        df['Column2'] = 'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing vectorized operation each time through the loop.  Every time through the loop you are assigning `'YES'` to the entire `Column2`.

Using `numpy` you could do:

```
import numpy as np

df['Column2'] = np.where(df['Column1'].str.contains('X'), 'YES', 'NO')
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
             Column1 Column2
0  ....X.X.X.X..X.X.     YES
1  ....X.X.X.X..X.X.     YES
2  ....X.X.X.X..X.X.     YES
3  ....X.X.X.X..X.X.     YES
4          ....F.F.F‬      NO
5          ....F.F.F      NO
6          ....F.F.F      NO
7          ....F.F.F      NO
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to find 'X'

```
if df['Column1'].str.find(r'X')>1:
```

you can even avoid the loop as follows

```
(df['Column1'].str.find(r'X')>1).map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```